# VBA error(9) Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

While executing the below script, I can't get rid of the `run time error 9`.

What I want to do is to search a specific cell value from sheet 2 and locate it in a range of cells in sheet 1.

Here is my script:

```
Public output() As Variant
Sub james()
Dim J As Object
Dim c As Object

Sheet2.Activate
ReDim ouput(3)
Set J = Cells(1, 1)

output(1) = J.Offset(0, 5).Value
output(2) = J.Offset(30, 5).Value
output(3) = J.Offset(60, 5).Value

Sheet1.Activate
Range("B7:B86").Select
For Each c In Selection
If c.Value = "output(1)" Then
    Exit For
End If
Next c
Rows(c.Row).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: index of array starts from 0 and not 1. The first element is `output(0)`

Comment: If you have a hard time wrapping your head around a zero-based index system, use [Option Base 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251511.aspx) in the declarations area of your module code sheet. Also see the [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) functions.

Answer (score 0):

@SearchAndResQ is right, if you wanted your array to start at 1, you have two options:

Use `Option Base 1` at the beginning of your module, or `Redim output(1 to 3)`

Also, you will want to change your `If` statement for:

```
If c.Value = output(1) then
```

All in all, this is a better version of your code:

```
Public output() As Variant

Sub james()
Dim J As Range
Dim c As Range

ReDim ouput(1 to 3)
Set J = Sheet2.Cells(1, 1)

output(1) = J.Offset(0, 5).Value
output(2) = J.Offset(30, 5).Value
output(3) = J.Offset(60, 5).Value

For Each c In Sheet1.Range("B7:B86")
   If c.Value = output(1) Then
       Exit For
   End If
Next c

Rows(c.Row).Select

End Sub
```